# Why adding 3 BYTEs fails, but DWORDs succeeds

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, addition

I am just beginning with `ASM`, so this question may show my lack of understanding.

I was trying to add 3 numbers to one another, the code below with `DWORD`s work as intended:

```
.data

val1 DWORD 25
val2 DWORD 23
val3 DWORD 20
sum  DWORD 0

.code
main proc
    mov eax,val1                
    add eax,val2        
    add eax,val3
    mov sum,eax

    invoke ExitProcess,0
```

However, as soon as I switch from `DWORD` to `BYTE`, like viz:

```
.data

val1 BYTE 25
val2 BYTE 23
val3 BYTE 20
sum  BYTE 0
```

My execution fails with `error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size`.

Now, my understanding is that a `BYTE` may contain any 8-bit unsigned integer from 0 - 255. Even using `DB` fails. Why is that? Thanks.

Comment: Because you have defined val1, val2, val3 and sum as byte when you use them in a memory operand (with MASM), MASM checks the size of the data with the size of the register. Since an 8 -bit byte and 32-bit register (EAX) are not the same size it raises an error. Since all of your types are byte you should be able to replace _EAX_ with _AL_ (the lower 8 bits of the 32-bit register _EAX_)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Perfect thanks! Now my understanding is clear. Will you please write this as an answer so I may accept the same. Quick question, how to visualise AL/AH in Visual Studio?

Comment: You can self answer the question. I suspect this is a duplicate, but I can't be bothered to look lol

Comment: In Visual studio your AL and AH are the low (and second lowest bytes) of EAX. So if visual studio is displaying EAX as 0x12345678 then 0x78 is in AL and 0x56 is in AH

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks a ton! My regards!